# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ID1'

Tags: python, linear-regression

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = {
'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID5'],
'RMSE': [10.05616902165789, 9.496130901397015, 9.857060740380899,9.528204292426823,9.491117416326155]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = df[['ID']]
y = df['RMSE']

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

preds = reg.predict(X)

mean_pred = preds.mean()

print('Mean of predicted RMSE values:', mean_pred)

how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because your column, `ID` only contains `str` objects, which makes it impossible to convert to `float`. **The `X` column must be numerical in order to work.**